# Cargar plantillas de Laravel a través de Javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Necesito crear formularios dinámicos utilizando el sistema de plantillas blade de laravel, el famoso @include('mi_vista'), pero para ello estoy usando javascript para que de acuerdo a la selección que haga desde un campo select que tengo previamente configurado me traiga el @include correspondiente dependiendo de dicha selección, no se si esto se pueda usar asi, en la imagen lo estoy configurando de la siguiente manera pero no me funciona.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php se ejecuta primero y javascript después, motivo por el que lo que propones no funcionará.

Para poder cargar una plantilla lo que tienes que hacer es que javascript, mediante AJAX o re direccionando a otra url, cargue la plantilla. Me explico: deberías hacer una llamada AJAX, por ejemplo, que haga que se ejecute una función dentro del controlador correspondiente, que devuelva la plantilla. A modo de ejemplo, el siguiente código (en producción) devuelve una plantilla u otra en función de si la petición es AJAX o no:

```
...

if (\Request::ajax()) {
            return \Response::json(
                \View::make(
                    'base.usrusuario.ver_usuarios_online_list',
                    ['usuarios' => $usuarios, 'modact' => $this->modact]
                )->render()
            );

        }

        return \View::make('base.usrusuario.ver_usuarios_online')->with(
            [
                'titulo' => $titulo,
                'modact' => $this->modact,
                'usuarios' => $usuarios
            ]
        );

...
```

Comment: Pedro Prada, muchisimas gracias funciono perfecto!!